# Difference between pointer to a reference and reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, reference

What is the difference between pointer to a reference, reference to a pointer and pointer to a pointer in C++?

Where should one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

First, a reference to a pointer is like a reference to any other variable:

```
void fun(int*& ref_to_ptr)
{
    ref_to_ptr = 0; // set the "passed" pointer to 0
    // if the pointer is not passed by ref,
    // then only the copy(parameter) you received is set to 0,
    // but the original pointer(outside the function) is not affected.
}
```

A pointer to reference is illegal in C++, because -unlike a pointer- a reference is just a concept that allows the programmer to make *aliases* of something else. A pointer is a **place in memory** that has the address of something else, but a reference is NOT.

Now the last point might not be crystal clear, if you insist on dealing with references as pointers. e.g.:

```
int x;
int& rx = x; // from now on, rx is just like x.
// Unlike pointers, refs are not real objects in memory.
int* p = &x; // Ok
int* pr = &rx; // OK! but remember that rx is just x!
// i.e. rx is not something that exists alone, it has to refer to something else.
if( p == pr ) // true!
{ ... }
```

As you can see from the above code, when we use the reference, we are not dealing with something separated from what it refers to. So, the address of a reference is just the address of what it refers to. Thats why there is no such thing called the address of the reference in terms of what *you* are talking about.

Comment: The most important point (as you have expressed) is that you can **not** get a pointer to a reference (or a reference to a reference) or anything like that. As the reference is just an alias to another obejct.

Comment: Ok but you have just made a poiner to a refernce : int* pr = &rx; could you explain that?

Comment: @Mateusz: No that doesn't.  It uses a reference (`rx`) to an object (`x`) to get a pointer to the object.  It is not a pointer to the reference.

Comment: I would suggest to rephrase the beginning of this answer. I wanted to know if I can create a pointer to a referenced object and google told me "A pointer to reference is illegal in C++" referring to this answer. So I thought int* pr = &rx is illegal.

Answer (score 61):

#### Pointer to a pointer

A **pointer** in C++ is just a value which stores a memory location (generally as a 32-bit value).

Let's say you had a user input integer value (`78` == `0x4E` in hex).

It would be stored in memory in a similar way to this (I'm purposely simplifying things for this example):

```
Memory address    Value
0x12345678        0x0000004E
```

If you wanted to create a "pointer" to this value, it would look like this in memory:

```
Memory address    Value
0x22334455        0x12345678
```

At memory address `0x22334455` you now have a "pointer" whose value is `0x12345678`, or the memory address of where the user input integer value (`0x4E`) is stored.

Let's say you wanted to create a "pointer" to this pointer value.  It would look like this:

```
Memory address    Value
0x11335577        0x22334455
```

You now have a new "pointer" value in memory which is storing the memory address of the previously-defined pointer value.

Pointers can be created like this indefinitely - the key is remembering that a pointer is just another value that the compiler interprets as a memory location (and it provides various access semantics such as `*` and `->` which are special to "pointer" types).

#### Reference to a pointer

A **reference** can be thought of as a view, or alias, on to another real object.  When you create a reference to a pointer called `myReference`, you are simply defining a new name called `myReference` which can be used to access the pointer which you have previous defined in memory.

Internally, references are implemented using pointers, but this is beyond the scope of your question.

References have restrictions over other types in C++ - for example, you *must* always initialize a reference to "refer" to a real object when you create it, while a pointer *may* point to memory which is invalid, or uninitialised.

#### Pointer to a reference

This doesn't exist.  As stated earlier, a reference is merely an alias to another object.  You can't "point" to a reference, because it isn't an object in itself but merely another name for a real object.

Of course, you can have a pointer to the object that a reference is referring to.  But now we are back in vanilla pointer territory.

#### Note about parameters

When you pass a parameter **by value** to a method or routine, you are essentially passing a "copy" of the object to the method.  Any changes you make to the value within the routine will be lost when the routine returns, because the parameter will be treated as a local variable in the context of the routine.

If you want to modify a parameter which is passed in so the client (calling) code can access the change, you must pass the parameter by **pointer** or by **reference**.

For example:

```
void myMethod(int myValue)
{
    // NOTE: This change will be lost to the caller!
    myValue = 5;
}

void myMethod2(int* myValue)
{
    // Correct way of modifying pointer parameter value
    *myValue = 5;
}

void myMethod3(int& myValue)
{
    // Correct way of modifying reference parameter value
    myValue = 5;
}
```

Let's now say that your method wants to allocate memory for a pointer.  You could be tempted to do this:

```
void myMethod4(int* myValue)
{
    // Warning: You will lose the address of the allocated
    // memory when you return!
    myValue = new int[5];
}
```

But remember, you are modifying the *copy* of the pointer value here, not the *real* pointer value.  Since you are wanting to modify the **pointer** in this routine, and not the **value** that the pointer "points" to, you need to pass it in as a "pointer to a pointer" or a "reference to a pointer":

```
void myMethod5(int** myValue)
{
    // Correct way of allocating memory in a method
    // via pointer-to-pointer
    *myValue = new int[5];
}

void myMethod6(int*& myValue)
{
    // Correct way of allocating memory in a method
    // via reference-to-pointer
    myValue = new int[5];
}
```

In these bottom 2 examples, the code which is calling `myMethod5` and `myMethod6` will correctly get the memory address of the newly-allocated memory via the `myValue` parameter pointer or reference.

Comment: "must always initialize a reference to "refer" to a real object when you create it" is not actually true.  You can pre-emptively bind a reference to a location which an object will occupy in the future.  You just can't allow lvalue-to-rvalue conversion until the object exists in its fully-constructed state.  Example: you can call a base class constructor with the address of a member variable.  Construction order dictates that the member doesn't exist yet, however storing a reference to it is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 13):

There is no such thing as a pointer to a reference.

Answer (score 6):

A reference is an abstraction away from pointers.  References are a bit harder to screw up, especially for novices, and are a bit more high level.

You don't *need* references. You can always use pointers.  However, sometimes code can be easier to read with them.

A typical beginner example is a linked list.  Imagine you have a variable called "list" that contains a pointer to the first one.  If you wanted to add something to the head, you'd need to give your add() a double pointer, since it needs to be able to modify "head". However, you can use a reference to a pointer instead.  Here, we want to use pointers in the list itself since we'll be mutating them, but the add() function will be clearer if we pass in a reference to the head of the list instead of a double pointer.

They're simply a style choice. If you're working on a larger project, you should go with the style of the project.  If not, you can use whatever you feel is preferable.  You should, however, be comfortable using all styles if you even hope to be a mildly successful C++ programmer.

It is also worthwhile that you can't have a pointer to a reference. This is because references are really just another name for another variable, which may be in some other scope.  Having a pointer to a reference doesn't make sense.  What you'd really want is just a pointer to whatever the original data was, no references involved.

Comment: "You don't _need_ references." No, **you** have never written any code where **you** needed them. Plenty of other people use operators, move semantics, templates where a variable may be a value or a reference and should just work either way without requiring endless near-duplication with/without asterisks/ampersands, 'pass by ref' without the code being a hideous soup of asterisks/ampersands, every caller having to rewrite, etc. It is inane to ignore whole swathes of the language that just cannot work without references & trash the rest as just "sometimes code can be easier to read with them".

Answer (score 4):

It is important to note that although a reference is not an object and therefore does not have an accessible address, a reference can be contained within an object and the containing object does have an address.

```
struct contains_ref
{
     int& ref;
     contains_ref(int& target) : ref(target) {}
};
```

The "reference is an alias" explanation is not incorrect, but is often accompanied by misleading claims.  A reference is not equivalent to the original object.  It has its own lifetime, determined by the scope or object that contains it, and not the object it refers to.  And a reference can outlive an object and be used to refer to a new object created at the same address.

Treat a reference as what it really is -- an abstraction around a pointer that excludes null as a valid value, and prevents reseating<sup>1</sup> -- and not something magic.  The only unusual property of a reference that isn't derived from its pointer nature is lifetime extension of temporaries.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually this is a consequence of the fact that C++ doesn't provide any syntax for referring to the reference itself rather than its target.  All operators, including the assignment operator, are simply applied to the target.

Comment: I took the liberty to open a question about one of your statements if you ever have a minute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245226/using-the-same-reference-for-a-new-object

Answer (score 0):

Just try and see for yourself what is each thing holding. The sample program simply prints the value for an int and the addresses of different entities:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int myInt ;
  int *ptr_to_myInt = &myInt;
  int *ptr_to_myInt_ref = ptr_to_myInt;

  myInt = 42;

  printf("myInt is %d\n",myInt);
  printf("ptr_to_myInt is %x\n",ptr_to_myInt);
  printf("ptr_to_myInt_ref is %x\n",ptr_to_myInt_ref);
  printf("&ptr_to_myInt is %x\n",&ptr_to_myInt);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myInt is 42
ptr_to_myInt is bffff858
ptr_to_myInt_ref is bffff858
&ptr_to_myInt is bffff854
```

So, the pointer to the int and the pointer to the reference of the int are exactly the same thing. This is obvious from the code, because the pointer to a reference is simply another way of aliasing a pointer (it is saying "hold the following address for me").

Now, the pointer also needs some space in memory, and if you print the reference to this pointer (the last printf statement) it simply indicates the place in memory where the pointer resides.

Comment: The question is asking bout `c++` and not `c`! Also *references* is a distinct topic from memory addresses, it is added in `c++`. They are somehow related but they are not the same.