# Pass by Pointers vs Pass by reference in functions c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I know this question is probably a duplicate, but I haven't found an answer that really states why should I use one over the other as they most likely will yield the same result. My question is when to use Pass by reference and when to use Pass by Pointer to a c++ functions.

Comment: First rule of pointers: Don't use pointers. ;) Other than that it really depends on use-case, but try to avoid pointers if you can.

Comment: @Ahmed refer it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177329/differences-between-passing-by-reference-and-passing-by-address/52253504#52253504

Comment: thanks for the help