# std::is_trivially_copyable<T> with references

Tags: c++, memory, reference, copy

I have a question that I cannot find a satisfying answer to: Why are references not considered trivially copyable?

```
std::is_trivially_copyable<int>::value == true
std::is_trivially_copyable<int&>::value == false
```

Example 1:

```
int a = 5;
int& b = a;
int c = -1;

std::memcpy(&c, &b, sizeof(b));
assert(c == a);
assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<int&>::value == false);
```

This works exactly as expected.

Example 2:

```
struct A
{
    int foo;
};

void test(const A& a)
{
    A a2{};
    std::memcpy(&a2, &a, sizeof(a));
    assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<const A&>::value == false);
    assert(std::memcmp(&a, &a2, sizeof(A)) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value);
    A a{1};
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why are references not considered trivially copyable? I must be missing something here.

Comment: "Trivially Copyable" implies a type that can be copied with `std::memcpy` or `std::memmove`.  That requires the types to have addresses, and [references do not have addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950779/is-there-any-way-to-find-the-address-of-a-reference).

Comment: In your example you are not coping a reference, but value "pointed" by that reference. So you are coping `a` not `b`, since `b` refers to `a`!

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: References do not satisfy requirements of `std::is_trivially_copyable`

Lets attempt to understand why `std::is_trivially_copyable<int>` returns `true`, and `std::is_trivially_copyable<int&>` returns false. Well, lets look at the c++ reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

It says

> The only trivially copyable types are scalar types, trivially copyable classes, and arrays of such types/classes (possibly cv-qualified).

Lets unpack that. What are `scalar types`? Here is the refence:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scalar

> If T is a scalar type (that is a possibly cv-qualified arithmetic, pointer, pointer to member, enumeration, or std::nullptr_t type), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

and per reference, it says that `is_scalar` depends on the output of `is_arithmetic` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic

`std::is_arithmetic_v<int>` returns `true` and this is why `std::is_trivially_copyable<int>` returns `true`.
`std::is_arithmetic_v<int&>` returns `false` requirements of `is_trivially_copyable<int&>` are not satisifed.
however, `std::is_arithmetic_v<int*>` returns `true` because `is_scalar` calls `std::is_pointer<int *>` which returns `true`