# C++ difference between ** and *& in parameter passing

Tags: c++

I have implemented operations on a list, one of them is add, and since i don't want to return anything, i read that i had to use **, and it works, but i saw on another place that it is passed as *&, but i don't know the difference

addNode( node *&head, int value)
addNode(node **head, int value)

What is the difference, and which one is better, or do they mean the same?
I know the second is pointer to a pointer.

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

The first (`**`) is a *pointer* to a pointer and the second (`*&`) is a *reference* to a pointer.

A reference and a pointer are conceptually quite similar. But there are some important differences, for example:

- A reference cannot be NULL (but it can refer to a pointer which points to NULL).
- You can't modify a reference to refer to something else.
- You need to dereference a pointer to access the value.

See this related question for more differences:

- [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: At least according to the article I found, it is a pointer to a reference and not the other way around. (I wasn't sure about which one it was myself, so I really don't know for sure.) The difference may be very subtle, but it could cause some confusion in rare cases.

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a reference (that's another difference between pointers and references by the way, and it's also mentioned on the page I linked to). See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898524/difference-between-pointer-to-a-reference-and-reference-to-a-pointer

Comment: Good point. I didn't think that through closely enough. I was just trying to think of it in terms of operator binding.

Answer (score 7):

With:

```
addNode( node *&head, int value)
```

...the type of `head` is "reference to pointer-to-node".

With:

```
addNode(node **head, int value)
```

... the type is "pointer-to-pointer-to-node".

A pointer and a reference are *not* the same thing.  A simple way to think of a reference is as a *dereferenced pointer*.

You would need different syntax to call both versions:

```
node* my_node = 0;
addNode(my_node, 0);  // syntax for first version
addNode(&my_node, 0); // syntax for 2nd version
```

There are semantic differences as well.  When you pass a pointer, you can pass NULL.  When you pass a reference, you can't.  This being a function that takes a ref-to-ptr confuses the matter a little, so let's change the problem a bit:

```
void make_string(string& str_ref)
{
  str_ref = "my str";
}

void make_string_again(string* str_ptr)
{
  *str_ptr = "my other string";
}
```

These two finctions do the same thing but one takes a `string` reference while the other takes a `string` pointer.  If you were to do this:

```
string str;
make_string(str); // OK
make_string_again(&str); // OK - &str is a pointer to a real string
make_string_again(0); // Not OK - compiles but will crash when function dereferences the null pointer
```

You can see it becomes difficult (but not impossible) to call `make_string` with a null pointer.  This could help you to implement better functions in the case where you expect that `make_string` will *never* be called with an invalid object.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between [pass by value](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/pass_by_value.htm#pass_by_value) and [pass by reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublib.boulder.ibm.com%2Finfocenter%2Fcomphelp%2Fv8v101%2Ftopic%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm&ei=j-SkTPHdAciKnQeEweCQAQ&usg=AFQjCNEv7lj4NAap5LfxFccHeBSebox8ew&sig2=l16XT7bS_pR4eJGhnlJ-MA). Pass by reference, basically, implicitly does the reference and dereference that the double pointer gets you.