# c++ object array + argument with reference and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, dynamic-memory-allocation

I don't understand the 2nd argument.
Whats is it exactly?
And most importantly he(the programmer) uses it to create a new array of Object objects , of num (the variable) size at the end.

```
void expand(const Object &s, Object* &children, int &num)
{
   ...
   children = new Object[num]; // <----
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you read a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It is, obviously, a reference to a pointer to `Object`. What's unclear about that?

Comment: It is ugly, but you can use the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to decipher most C and C++ declarations.

Comment: Algirdas Preidžius: So the function takes as a 2nd argument the MEMORY ADDRESS of the pointer named children , which points to type Object?

Comment: @DIMITRIOS That's why I suggested reading a C++ book. Reference != memory address. Probably you are confusing references, and address-of operator?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834067/c-difference-between-and-in-parameter-passing) for some explanations on `*&` (as well as `**`).

Comment: @DIMITRIOS I updated your question, focusing on the gist of it, hope you don't mind. Don't forget to *accept* an answer BTW!

Answer (score 2):

Read it from right to left:

When you reach a `*`, replace it by pointer to.
When you reach a `&`, replace it by reference of.

So `children` will be:
A reference of a pointer to an `Object`.

Comment: I like your answer, but I posted a new one, to augment the answer's section. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Second argument: Object* &children
Object* says that children is a pointer to Object type.
& prevent from receiving a copy of children from calling scope and lets us to work directly with argument variable, so when you change children :

```
children = new Object[num];
```

you change the argument variable in calling scope and after expand function returns, you have access to:

```
new Object[num]
```

via the argument variable that you passed to expand function.

Passing arguments by reference, is another way to receive information from function (It has other usages too).

Answer (score 1):

It's:

> a reference of a pointer to an `Object`

The reason is that because it allocates dynamically memory, he probably wants this change to `children` to be reflected in the caller of the function (probably `main()`).