# Receiving object in the reference variable

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between pointer to a reference and reference to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898524/difference-between-pointer-to-a-reference-and-reference-to-a-pointer)

Hi,
   I could not understand `get(Event*& pEvent)`... Is it passing the address of the object pEvent to the reference of `pEvent`..`(Event*& pEvent)`...The reference will exist as a local scope within the function isnt it....

```
void classA::func()
{
 Event* pEvent = NULL;
  if ( get((pEvent) )
  {
   ......//definition;
  }
}
bool ClassA::get(Event*& pEvent)
{
 ...//definition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo(someType& o)` means that a reference of an object is passed rather than a copy of the object. In your case a reference to an `Event` pointer is passed. Basically that means that changes inside the function will make changes to the variable being passed visible to the caller of the function. E.g.

```
void get(Event* e)
{
   e = null;
}

void get2(Event*& e)
{
   e = null;
}
```

If you call them:

```
Event *e = new Event();
get(e);
// e has not changed
get2(e);
// e is null now
```

Answer (score 0):

`get(Event*& pEvent)` means a pointer `pEvent` is being received by reference. So now the pointer itself is modifiable inside the function.

```
p = &obj;  // p points to obj
get(p);  // p = pEvent is modified to 0
// now outside p points to '0'
```

It it was `getEvent(Event* pEvent)`, then you can not modify the pointer itself. So whatever you assign to `pEvent` inside `get()`, outside it won't be modified.