# c++ trick with *& what does it mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between pointer to a reference and reference to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898524/difference-between-pointer-to-a-reference-and-reference-to-a-pointer)

I am newbie in C++ and I work on a pretty complicated project. When I tried to figure out something, I saw one interesting thing:

```
n->insertmeSort((Node *&)first);
```

When we deep into insertmeSort, we can see the same:

```
    void Node::insertme(Node *&to)
{
   if(!to) {
      to=this;
      return;
   }
   insertme(value>to->value ? to->right : to->left);
}
```

So the reason of my question is: `Node *&` - asterisk and ampersand, for what?

It looks pretty tricky, and interesting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a reference to a pointer. Like any regular reference, but the underlying type is a pointer.

Prior to references pointer-by-reference had to be done with double-pointers (and some C-minded folk still do, I occasionally being one of them).

Lest there be any doubt, try this to really sink it in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void foo (int *& p)
{
    std::cout << "&p: " << &p << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *q = NULL;
    std::cout << "&q: " << &q << std::endl;
    foo(q);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output** (your values will be different , but &p == &q)

```
&q: 0x7fff5fbff878
&p: 0x7fff5fbff878
```

It is hopefully pretty clear that `p` in `foo()` is indeed a reference to pointer `q` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a trick, it is simply the type -- "reference to pointer to `Node`".

`n->insertmeSort((Node *&)first);` calls `insertmeSort` with the result of casting `first` to a `Node*&`.

`void Node::insertme(Node *&to)` declares `insertme` as taking a reference to a pointer to a `Node` as an argument.

Example of how references and pointers work:

```
int main() {
    //Initialise `a` and `b` to 0
    int a{};
    int b{};
    int* pointer{&a}; //Initialise `pointer` with the address of (&) `a`
    int& reference{a};//Make `reference` be a reference to `a`
    int*& reference_to_pointer{pointer_x}; 

    //Now `a`, `*pointer`, `reference` and `*reference_to_pointer`
    //can all be used to manipulate `a`.
    //All these do the same thing (assign 10 to `a`):
    a = 10;
    *pointer = 10;
    reference = 10;
    *reference_to_pointer = 10;

    //`pointer` can be rebound to point to a different thing. This can
    //be done directly, or through `reference_to_pointer`.
    //These lines both do the same thing (make `pointer` point to `b`):
    pointer = &b;
    reference_to_pointer = &b;

    //Now `b`, `*pointer` and `*reference_to_pointer` can
    //all be used to manipulate `b`.
    //All these do the same thing (assign 20 to `b`):
    b = 20;
    *pointer = 20;
    *reference_to_pointer = 20;
}
```

Comment: Yes, just a reference type to a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

*& means you are passing a pointer by reference.  So in this case you are passing a pointer to an object by reference to this function.  without the reference, this line would have no effect

```
if(!to) {
  to=this;
  return;
```

}