# c++ void someFunction(Object * & x)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, avl-tree

I'm working on an AVL tree with given code, and I get pointers and I get references but I don't get this:

```
void remove(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t) {

BinaryNode * & t
```

This appears to me as a pointer to a reference? But searching StackOverflow yields:

[Difference between pointer to a reference and reference to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898524/difference-between-pointer-to-a-reference-and-reference-to-a-pointer)

> **Pointer to a reference**
>
> This doesn't exist. As stated earlier, a reference is merely an alias
> to another object. You can't "point" to a reference, because it isn't
> an object in itself but merely another name for a real object.

I strongly suspect this is a question answered many times but searching for C++ * & is rather difficult.

Comment: Read it the other way around: `BinaryNode * &` is a reference to a pointer to a `BinaryNode` object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - cheers, wanna answer so I can hit the check else I'll just delete this?

Comment: A pointer is like any other variable - the only thing distinguishing a pointer from other variables is that its value is an address (of another variable, of an object, etc).   Passing a pointer by reference means the same as passing any other variable by reference.   If the reference is not `const` qualified, it can be used to change the pointer (e.g. to point at something else).     There is no such thing as a pointer to a reference though.   `BinaryNode *&t`  means that `t` is a reference to a pointer (it is equivalent to `(BinaryNode *) &t` not to `BinaryNode *(&t)` [which is not allowed]).

Comment: So, the rule of thumb for determining a type is that from the name, sweep right, then sweep left. There is nothing to the right of `t`, so sweeping left gives you a reference to a pointer to a `BinaryNode`. Way easier than the spiral rule.